# Why is my material design not rendering properly (Android Studio)?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, material-design

I'm using Android Studio 1.5.1, and my material design is giving render errors. Here's the `styles.xml` page, without material edits:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

And here's this code with Material edits.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

For some reason, it gives out

> "NOTE: One or more layouts are missing the layout_width or
>   layout_height attributes. These are required in most layouts." etc. in
>   the preview. Running on my Nexus 6P also gives the same problem. I'm
>   using Android 6.0.1. It also fails to find "toolbarStyle". I'm a
>   beginner, so can anyone help with this?

**EDIT**: My "automatically add missing attributes" link is not working.

Comment: Add your layout xml also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some misunderstanding between concepts, if you use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` you already are using *Material Design*.

From [How to set up your Android app project to use Material Design with AppCompat](http://www.thewirelessguy.co.uk/2014/10/setting-android-app-project-use-material-design-appcompat/)

> AppCompat v21.+’s Theme.AppCompat extends Theme.Base.AppCompat which
>   extends Theme.Platform.AppCompat which extends android:Theme.Material
>   on 21+ devices (i.e. Android 5.0 Lollipop) so you only need to extend
>   Theme.AppCompat to use Material theme if you are using the AppCompat
>   v21 (or above) library.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful.